# Error 3 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'Socket *'

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I have problem when I implamante default constructor but I have error

> Error 3   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to
>   'Socket *'    Webserver.h 164 1   Project2_SocketLib

```
Socket.h
    //SOCKET Accept(sockaddr* clientInfo,int* clientInfoSize)
    SOCKET Accept()
    {
        static int size = sizeof(sockaddr);
        return accept(this->hSocket, 0,0);
    }
Webserver.h
    Webserver(short port_to_listen,request_func rf,HWND Hwnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        Socket in(port_to_listen,"INADDR_ANY", true, Hwnd, true);

        //request_func = rf;

        while (1) {
            Socket* ptr_s =(void*) in.Accept();

            unsigned ret;
            _beginthreadex(0,0,Request, ptr_s,0,&ret);
        }

    }
```

Comment: typedef UINT_PTR        SOCKET;

Comment: What is the relationship between SOCKET and Socket? Presumably SOCKET is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are explicitly type casting to `void *`

```
 Socket* ptr_s =(void*) in.Accept();
```

Should be,

```
Socket sock = in.Accept();
```

`Accept` returns SOCKET. No need to convert it to `void *` or `Socket *`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
Socket* ptr_s =static_cast<Socket*>( in.Accept());
```

Answer (score -1):

In C++, unlike in C, a `void*` can't be implicitly converted to a pointer to object. Instead, you should cast directly to the target pointer type:

```
Socket* ptr_s = reinterpret_cast<Socket*>(in.Accept());
```

Note: Prefer C++-style casts over C-style casts. They are more explicit in their intent and they are easier to search for.